# Python, calculating time difference

Tags: python-2.7, strptime

I'm parsing logs generated from multiple sources and joined together to form a huge log file in the following format;

```
My_testNumber: 14, JobType = testx.

ABC 2234

**SR 111**
1483529571  1   1   Wed Jan  4 11:32:51 2017    0   4
    datatype someRandomValue
SourceCode.Cpp 588

DBConnection failed

TB 132


**SR 284**
1483529572  0   1   Wed Jan  4 11:32:52 2017    5010400     4
    datatype someRandomXX
SourceCode2.cpp 455

DBConnection Success

TB 102

**SR 299**

1483529572  0   1   **Wed Jan  4 11:32:54 2017**    5010400     4
    datatype someRandomXX
SourceCode3.cpp 455

ConnectionManager Success
```

....
(there are dozens of SR Numbers here)

Now i'm looking a smart way to parse logs so that it calculates time differences in seconds for each testNumber and SR number
like
My_testNumber:14 it subtracts SR 284 and SR 111 time (difference would be 1 second here), for SR 284 and 299 it is 2 seconds and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your posted log file and save the corresponding data accordingly. Then, you can work with the data to get the time differences. The following should be a decent start:

```
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import permutations # if order matters
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime
import re


sr_numbers = []
dates = []

# Loop through the file and get the test number and times
# Save the data in a list

pattern = re.compile(r"(.*)\*{2}(.*)\*{2}(.*)")
for line in open('/Path/to/log/file'):
    if '**' in line:
        # Get the data between the asterisks
        if 'SR' in line:
            sr_numbers.append(re.sub(pattern,"\\2", line.strip()))
        else:
            dates.append(datetime.strptime(re.sub(pattern,"\\2", line.strip()), '%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
    else:
        continue

# Use hashmap container (ordered dictionary) to make it easy to get the time differences
# Using OrderedDict here to maintain the order of the order of the test number along the file
log_dict = OrderedDict((k,v) for k,v in zip(sr_numbers, dates))

# Use combinations to get the possible combinations (or permutations if order matters) of time differences
time_differences = {"{} - {}".format(*x):(log_dict[x[1]] - log_dict[x[0]]).seconds for x in combinations(log_dict, 2)}

print(time_differences)

# {'SR 284 - SR 299': 2, 'SR 111 - SR 284': 1, 'SR 111 - SR 299': 3}
```

#### Edit:

Parsing the file without relying on the asterisks around the dates:

```
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import permutations # if order matters
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime
import re


sr_numbers = []
dates = []

# Loop through the file and get the test number and times
# Save the data in a list

pattern = re.compile(r"(.*)\*{2}(.*)\*{2}(.*)")
for line in open('/Path/to/log/file'):
    if 'SR' in line:
        current_sr_number = re.sub(pattern,"\\2", line.strip())
        sr_numbers.append(current_sr_number)
    elif line.strip().count(":") > 1:
        try:
            dates.append(datetime.strptime(re.split("\s{3,}",line)[2].strip("*"), '%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
        except IndexError:
            #print(re.split("\s{3,}",line))
            dates.append(datetime.strptime(re.split("\t+",line)[2].strip("*"), '%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
    else:
        continue


# Use hashmap container (ordered dictionary) to make it easy to get the time differences
# Using OrderedDict here to maintain the order of the order of the test number along the file
log_dict = OrderedDict((k,v) for k,v in zip(sr_numbers, dates))

# Use combinations to get the possible combinations (or permutations if order matters) of time differences
time_differences = {"{} - {}".format(*x):(log_dict[x[1]] - log_dict[x[0]]).seconds for x in combinations(log_dict, 2)}

print(time_differences)

# {'SR 284 - SR 299': 2, 'SR 111 - SR 284': 1, 'SR 111 - SR 299': 3}
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: Do you know if there isn't any ** involved in time? like  instead of **Wed Jan  4 11:32:54 2017** , its just any time like Fri Jan 06 11:35:50 2017? Actually i used Bold but in the output it came like ** Wed**, let me update the log here

Comment: Sure i'll do shortly, but do you see any issues with the following 1483528298 1 1 Wed Jan  4 11:43:38 2017 0 4, getting output as ['1483528298\t1\t1\tWed Jan  4 11:43:38 2017\t0\t4\n']

Comment: Looks like the fields in that line are `tab-delimited`. So, just handle it in the `except` part of the code by splitting on `\t`. I will edit and show you what I mean.